# How to configure SBT to produce separate jars for dependencies and application code?

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

I'm using SBT as a build tool for spark projects.  I'm able to create a fat jar of my dependencies using the `sbt-assembly` plugin.

However, this produces a ~120M jar, mostly of dependencies which I need to keep uploading to S3 to run my code -- this takes 3-5 minutes to do.  Not a lot of time, but fairly annoying.

What would improve things a lot would be to have SBT produce a jar of the dependencies (which changes rarely), and a small jar of my application code which I should be able to upload in a few seconds.

Is this possible?  I'm pretty new to SBT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sbt-assembly` supports out-of-the-box [splitting project application jar from dependency jar](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#splitting-your-project-and-deps-jars). To produce just the dependency jar execute

```
sbt assemblyPackageDependency
```

To produce jar with just your project application code define `assemblyOption` as follows

```
assemblyOption in assembly := (assemblyOption in assembly).value.copy(includeScala = false, includeDependency = false)
```

and execute `sbt assembly` as usual.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to create both jars, upload to S3, and run using 
`spark-submit  --jars s3://<bucket path>/<project>-deps.jar s3://<bucket path>/<project>.jar`